Limit Firebase Authentication to only allowing 1 domain
I am making an iOS app and want to make it so that only people with a certain domain (Ex: dog.com) can access the app. I have already coded it so that my app will only permit users with that domain to enter, but when a user creates an account they are blocked from entering the rest of the app but  they still created an account that firebase picks up on.
I would like to have firebase block not create acounts for other domains, is this possible.
sorry if this does not make sense I am a very new programmer and it is my first time posting a question.
PS: I am using the free Firebase verison if that affects anything.
Thank you
I tried to add the domain I wanted but it still allows other domains through.

You can't do this using only unpaid services.  It requires the use of blocking functions using Cloud Functions, which requires a payment method on file on the blaze plan.
